# Figure-handling similar to Word+Origin, as implementation using LaTeX

Tags: graphs, msword

When putting a figure based on an Origin-file into Word, it is possible to double-click on that figure later in the finished Word-document to open the original origin-file (if available on the computer).
Is there a tool for a similar functionality in LaTeX/PDF, i.e. a click/double-click on a graph opens the original data? It is not necessary to have it connected to Origin, it also can be opened as raw data in a text file (if the data was made available as a text file).

Comment: yes, it is.You need to use for example `sumatra` viewer and accordingly set your LaTeX editor.

Comment: How could I do that then?

Comment: I cant tell you due to lack of information, what you use. I'm not familiar nor with Word nor with Origin. Sumatra is free and you can download (use google to find it).

Comment: @Zarko: The question is more: How do I include graphs/images in LaTeX, such that I can achieve a similar effect to the effect described above. How does that work in combination with Sumatra?

Comment: yes, it should work.

Comment: @Zarko: But how? That was the question

Comment: I install Sumatra, inform my editor (WinEdt)  that I use it for pdf viewer, than go to the editor PDF viewer window and activate SyncTeX. Since i don't know, which editor you use, I can't tell what you should do.